# "Through" and "through to"

Tags: prepositions

Could anyone explain the difference between these examples?

> 1- Does this bus go ***through to*** Santa Fe?
>
> 2- Does this bus go ***through*** Santa Fe?
>
> 3- Does this bus go ***to*** Santa Fe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - This one sounds weird to me. Maybe "through to" in this question means "all the way to", so in that case it's asking if the bus goes all the way to (as far as) Santa Fe.

2 - Does this bus pass through Santa Fe on the way to somewhere else? The bus may or may not make a stop in Santa Fe, but the asker is wondering whether the route goes through Santa Fe. EDIT: in case using the word "through" in my answer doesn't help, it's asking whether the bus goes somewhere (anywhere, Santa Fe or somewhere else) *by way of* or *via* Santa Fe.

3 - Does this bus make a stop in Santa Fe?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the explanation of the first one.(as far as) Another example: He walked, dripping, through to the bedroom.

Comment: What I meant by "as far as" was "as great a distance as". Does the bus go a great enough distance that it will reach Santa Fe? But I'm actually not sure if that's exactly the meaning here - as an American English speaker this question sounds slightly strange to me.

Comment: I probably wouldn't say that other statement either - "He walked, dripping, through to the bedroom". But I'd probably understand that to mean "He walked and dripped water the whole way from wherever he was until he reached the bedroom".

Comment: While using "as far as X" or "through to X", do we understand that he might not reach X ? I mean maybe not reaching X will be sufficent for him ?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden I don't think so. When you're talking about going "to" a place or "as far as" a place, it's usually understood that the place will be reached. "towards" on the other hand can be used to mean "in the direction of" and not necessarily all the way there.

Comment: Hmm I asked this question because I had just read a answer saying: "It is similar to saying I will fly as far as 1000 miles. You are saying you will fly up to 1000 miles (as far as) but perhaps you will actually fly less than 1000. A thousand is your limit. The maximum distance you will fly. As far as you will fly."

Comment: @TalhaÖzden I understand your confusion now. Weirdly, these are two different senses of "as far as" - what I meant in my answer was "all the way to". Ex.: "I will go as far as Idaho, then I will turn back around." But it can also mean "no farther than". Ex.: "I will only go as far as Idaho, if that." The meaning depends on the context.